# How to transform ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList to "xml"?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, androidx

How can I set `ViewCompat` via xml instead of code?

```
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(
view,    ColorStateList.valueOf(...));
```

Answer (score -1):

in xml use:
app:setBackgroundTintList